# Why CountDownLatch sometimes doesn't release threads when count gets to zero?

Tags: java, swing

I was building a simple dialog, that is able to be dismissed by pressing a button or `Esc` button. I was using CountDownLatch to wait before dismissing the dialog, and called `.countDown()` from various listeners.

I ran into the following problem - pressing "X" on the window calls `.countDown()` and results in dialog dismissal, while pressing button results in calling the same code, but the thread does not resume execution. What could be the problem?

Compilable/runnable example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class StrangeDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public StrangeDialog(JFrame parent) {
        super(parent, true); // removing this line fixes things

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                System.out.println(latch);
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println(latch);
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        setSize(100,100);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StrangeDialog dialog = new StrangeDialog(null);
        try {
            dialog.latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        dialog.setVisible(false);
        System.out.println("Released");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just close the dialog in the event handler for the escape key? Also, the window listener isn't really needed since you have already specified its default close operation to be `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`. Is this just an exercise in using a `CountDownLatch`?

Comment: WindowListener is needed to call the dismissal logic, namely .countDown.

Comment: If you need to use a `CountDownLatch` to freeze up a different thread while you are waiting for the dialog to close, then yes, the `WindowListener` logic is necessary. However, the other thread should not need to tell the dialog to close - the dialog can take care of that logic itself. Even if you insist on having the other thread instigate the closing of the dialog, you _still need to do it on the event dispatch thread_ via a call to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() { public void run() { dialog.dispose(); } } );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a modal dialog.  Basically the code does not progress past `StrangeDialog dialog = new StrangeDialog(null);` until the window closes.

try:

```
final StrangeDialog dialog = new StrangeDialog(null);
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { dialog.setVisible(true); } });
```

in main() to open the window and it will work as expected.

Comment: You are right, but a small addition - it doesn't get past `setVisble(true)`, specifically.